# How do I measure parallel and sequential execution time in Apache Spark and Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to check time taken for both parallel and sequential task.

You'll find my code below, but for parallel task is taking more time than sequential. How can I resolve this? My primary aim is to achieve parallel execution using Spark Context:

```
object PrlAndSeqCheck {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      prlFunction()
      seqFunction()
  }

  def prlFunction(): Unit ={
    var list=List(2,6,8,9,6,8,9,8,100,1001,12,49,484,48,29,39,49);
    val conf=new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("word count")
    val sc=new SparkContext(conf)
    val t1=System.nanoTime()
    val rdd= sc.parallelize(list)
    val rdd2=rdd.map(r=>r*1000)

    var n=rdd2.reduce((a,b)=>if( a>b) a else b)
    println(" parrallel result "+n)

    val t2=System.nanoTime()
    println("Parralle Time "+(t2-t1))
  }

  def seqFunction(): Unit ={
    val t1=System.nanoTime()
    var list=List(2,6,8,9,6,8,9,8,100,1001,12,49,484,48,29,39,49);
    //var list2=List();
    var list2= list.map(a=>a*1000)
    val n=list2.reduce((a,b)=>if( a>b) a else b)
    println("Sequence result "+n)
    val t2=System.nanoTime()
    println("Sequence Time "+(t2-t1))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is to be expected. For such a small task, Spark is an overkill and has a large overhead. If the data fits in memory, standard scala collections are the first choice, and I would only use Spark for really large data.

If the computations are very cpu intensive, you can think about using multi-threading within scala, e.g. by using parallel collections.

Comment: Hi Raphael,Thank you for your answer.I understood what you mean.And I wanted to know, my code written above is correct for parallel and sequence programming in Apache Spark? and will it works for large data with other data resource(Data from HDFS or local text file of large data)?

Comment: I am new to Spark and Scala, Please help